# Need help identifying vascular structures in brain matter

Tags: neuroscience, human-anatomy, cancer, anatomy

I am working on PET images of the brain. The neuro-oncologist I'm working with identified 2 large high-intensity regions as vascular structures. I've been meaning to ask what structures these are exactly, but he's on vacation so I'm turning to you guys for help.

I've colored the 2 vascular structures in blue and red: The pictures show the axial (upper left), coronal (lower left) and sagittal (lower right) views of the brain.

[image: Brain Vessels (vessels are higher intensity)]

I've tried googling this, but this turns out to be less straight-forward than I thought and I'd like confirmation from someone that knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As these are very large, they seem to me likely to be [sinuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dural_venous_sinuses); the central one in red right along the midline is the superior sagittal sinus.

I think your blue traces may mark differently named sinuses, though they are all connected.

As a disclaimer, I'm more familiar with venous sinuses in the rodent brain, as they are important to avoid during rodent brain surgeries. Presumably the human ones are good to avoid when you poke things in there, too, but I haven't done as much of that, and anything I've done with human brain anatomy has already had these sorts of artifacts removed. If you need a specific anatomical reference from a cranial anatomy expert, I wouldn't rely on this answer too closely, but hopefully it leads you to where you need.

Comment: Thanks! this was actually what I was looking for, I have my sinuses in question to be the superior sagittal sinus and the straight sinus.

Comment: @nibs The straight sinus is on the midline; your bottom right image may be straight sinus but the other two are not. Transverse perhaps. Probably far easier to tell if you can threshold your images and look in 3D.